# How async / await can help in ASP.Net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, async-await, threadpool

Using async / await in action method of MVC controller can scale up the web application because at await the request thread of Asp.Net thread pool is freed up so that it can process other requests in the IIS queue for this worker process. This means that if we limit the Queue Length of worker process to 10, and send 50 - 100 requests to async action, the IIS should not return HTTP 503 error as there will always be a free thread from Asp.Net Thread Pool to server the incoming requests.

I have a WebApi that does the calculation as given below:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public int GetSum(int x, int y, int timeDelay = 1)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(timeDelay*1000);
        int result = x + y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

This action method just delays for given number of seconds before returning the sum result to the calling code. Very basic web api just to mimic the long running code.

Next is the MVC async action that awaits for the result:

```
public class ThreadStarvationController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> CallGetSumWithDelayAsync(int num1 = 5, int num2 = 8, int timeDelay = 60)
    {
        int callingThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        ThreadStarvationModel model = new ThreadStarvationModel();

        string url = "http://localhost:8111/api/values/GetSum?x=" + num1 + "&y=" + num2 + "&timeDelay=" + timeDelay;

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {

            // here still using the same request thread...
            // following line will force await to free up the request thread and wait asynchronouly               //for the response.
            model.ResponseFromWebService = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

            // here we can be on the same request thread or anyother thread... more likely on //another other thread than 
            // request thread.
        }

        int returningThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        model.CallingThreadId = callingThreadId;
        model.ReturningThreadId = returningThreadId;

        return this.View(model);
    }
}
```

The WebApi and MVC are hosted on IIS. The MVC website is limited to only 10 requests in queue.

When the client calls MVC async method after 15 or 20 requests the IIS sends HTTP 503 error which means that the IIS Queue is full with requests.

Here is the console application code that calls the MVC async method. It schedules 30 tasks and executed them in parallel.

```
          List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
        for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:8333/ThreadStarvation/CallGetSumWithDelayAsync?num1=" + x + "&num2=" + x + "&timeDelay=1";

            Task stringDataTask = new Task(() =>
            {
                using (HttpClient webClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    string data = webClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", data);
                }
            });


            taskList.Add(stringDataTask);
        }

        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

        Parallel.ForEach(taskList, item => item.Start());

        Console.WriteLine("================== START {0} ===========================", startTime);

        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("================= THE END {0} ============================", endTime);
```

When this runs, after 20 or so requests I get HTTP 503 error message.

If I use synchronous MVC action, the result is still the same. I know that with async / await different threads are used before and after await.

All I want to prove is that using async / await will scale up the web application.

Comment: Which MVC is throwing the 503? Your `ThreadStarvationController` controller? Are your controllers hosted on different app pools?

Comment: If your API is hosted under the same application pool as your web app, then it shares a threadpool. That means that - while the thread used to execute the MVC action is freed up - you still have `n` threads in use by your API.

Comment: The WebAPi and MVC website both are on separate application pool, hence separate worker process.

Comment: Yuval Itzchakov: ThreadStarvationController controller is hosted on its own app pool and has limited IIS pool Queue length to 10.
Yes The MVC and WebApi both hosted on IIS with their own app pools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are confusing pool queues. There are 5 places where ASP.NET requests can become queued on an IIS server.

1. Application pool queue
2. IIS worker process
3. CLR threadpool queue
4. Integrated mode global queue
5. Classic mode application queue

The Queue Length you are setting to 10 is HTTP.SYS: Application pool queue.

When you use async/awat you are using ASP.NET: CLR threadpool queue.

That is the reason why you get 503 error even with async/await.

On the other hand, [here there is a wonderful article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) about scalling web app with async/await that can help you.

[EDIT] I had just found [this article](http://blog.leansentry.com/2013/07/all-about-iis-asp-net-request-queues/) about request queuing that can help too.

Comment: Thank you jlvaquero. I have read "Stephen Cleary's article and thats when I decided to write this application.
From your answer is it true that the request thread of ASP.Net and the back ground thread thats executed by await are taken from Asp.Net threadPool?

Comment: @user1039644: There is no "background thread that's executed by await". The whole point of `await` is that it *doesn't* use a thread.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary. Not sure if OP is understanding me. I'm not a expert in the field. Can you clarify the situation better than me?

Comment: Thanks Stephen & jlvaquero for commenting.

If async / await is not using asp.net: CLR thread pool thread then in above application in question there must be a thread available almost all the time to serve incoming requests as the async action method only calls WebApi asynchronously. If this is true then i should not get HTTP 503 error message from "ASP.NET: CLR threadpool queue".

Also if await doenst use any thread then how it calls GetStringAsync() method?

I apologies for asking too many questions but Im still not confident enough to assume that using asyn/await will scale ASP.Net MVC app.

Comment: @user1039644: I'm not sure why you're seeing a 503; there's a lot of moving parts in your example. I have a simple proof-of-concept test [here](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/5796697). Regarding your `await` question: `await Method()` is the same as `var task = Method(); await task;`, so the method is actually called *before* the `await`.

Comment: @StephenCleary - Thanks for the code sample. I can see the difference in sync and async method behaviour. When the request thread reaches “await Task.Delay(1000);” in async Get(int id) method, it gets freed up and goes back to the threadPool. 
I would still like to refactor my code to not to get 503 error when calling async action method. 
Regarding await question thanks for the clarification. I realise that it’s the Task.Run() that spans out thread not await. But where that Task thread comes from? Is that thread from Asp.Net threadpool?

Again much appreciate your help n support on this.

Comment: @user1039644: There are actually two different kinds of tasks: Delegate Tasks execute on the thread pool; they're the kind of tasks that most people think of. But there's also Promise Tasks, which do not "run" anywhere; tasks returned from `async` methods are Promise Tasks. I have a couple blog posts [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html) and [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html). Also, my blog post [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) may explain it better.