# ASP.NET Web Performance

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, web, iis

I have a ASP.NET web server application (Framework 4.7.1) I'm trying to understand why performance is limited in specific scenarios and what I can do to optimize or increase it. It is written to be async all the way down. It is using Kestrel on IIS.

I am attempting to execute as many requests per second using WebSurge (a load testing app) to call Web API service method that takes a specified number of milliseconds on the query string which simply executes an async Task.Delay for that amount of time, and then navigate through different pages of the application.

When this delay is small, e.g. 50 ms or below and hundreds of requests per second are being executed for this Web API call via WebSurge, the performance is excellent, other quick web service requests on different pages held up, and pages don't take long at all to load up. However, as I increase this delay to two seconds or more and have 32 threads attempting to hit the server and respond as fast as it can, the performance starts to slow to a crawl.

As I said, everything in the website should be async all the way down. What is the performance bottleneck here?

I’m not sure what additional information is required. The CPU usage is low and all I’m doing is navigating through the same few three or four different pages as a single user that calls some Web APIs that retrieve data from the database that are all normally very fast under no load (under 30 ms), in addition to this is executing in WebSurge a singular API call hundreds of times or however many times it can, that is just an async Task.Delay for a specified time. So as I increase this time from 10 ms to 2 s and hit it with WebSurge increasing the threads from 8 to 16 to 32 with minimal time between request calls, as soon as I hit 32 users and a 2s async delay time, the navigation of one user between pages starts to become slow. I can look at the underlying pending API calls for the pages where these requests run pretty quick (10, 30, 50 ms), but many of them just sit in pending state for several seconds. So what I’m doing is simulating a server load trying to figure out why it slows to a crawl with so few users. The CPU usage is low so a lot of async processing is growing on, but I would expect those long running async task calls not to impact the processing of the web pages that have much quicker requests happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Thread pool exhaustion is my initial guess

Comment: What exact OS are you running on?

Comment: What is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=net-5.0 set to?

Comment: do you use asp.net session ?

Comment: OS is Windows 10.

It does NOT user ASP.NET session.

I've tried updating processModel settings in the corresponding machine.config files for the Framework to MS recommended settings for tuning as specified here: http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/Explained:_ASP.NET_Formula_for_Reducing_Contention

I've also tried changing applicationPool settings in ASPNet.config file.<br/>

Neither seems to have any impact.

Comment: `OS is Windows 10.` Which specific _version_ of Windows 10?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro. Version 10.0.19043 Build 19043.

Comment: Windows pro has a 10 connection limit for IIS. Which almost certainly explains what you are seeing.

Comment: So are you saying that IIS is effectively holding these 10 connections for the Task.Delay call that are slow and queuing up the others and that is the bottleneck? That would explain the timeout I see if I don't increase the request time out in ms for each request to be handled. Can I presume that Windows Server does not have this limit?

Comment: why not review this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855387/how-async-await-can-help-in-asp-net-application

Comment: where is some code?

Comment: The code is fairly simple. The Web API for delay is:
     public async Task Delay(int ms)
     {
            await Task.Delay(ms);
     }

Any other code (at least running in this scenario) is just a quick DB call using the async/await pattern.

Comment: `So are you saying that IIS is effectively holding these 10 connections for the Task.Delay call that are slow and queuing up the others and that is the bottleneck?` I suspect so, yes. `Can I presume that Windows Server does not have this limit?` Yes.